# My job entitles looking at bad things (Nudity and Vulgar Images). Do these break my fast?

Tags: salat, sawm, wudu

I work in content moderation for a social app company. Basically I delete the posts, pictures, videos that are vulgar. Which should not be up there. 80% of these things contain nudity and pornographic stuff. Do these break my wudu or sawm/fasting? These things do not bring me any comfort but I am really worried about my fasting.

Comment: Every action is based on intention. You should search for things that invalidate fasting